# respond_to do |format| format.js not working in rails 6.1.3

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-6

application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");


require("bootstrap");
require("jquery");
require('popper.js');
require("channels/jquery.nice-select.min.js");
require("channels/owl.carousel.min.js");

require("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free");
```

contacts_conttroller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

     respond_to do |format|
  
     if @contact.save
       ContactMailer.with(contact: @contact).notification.deliver_now
        format.html {redirect_to contacts_path}
        format.js {  }
    
     else 
      format.html {render :index}
      format.json {render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
    end
  end
end

private ##

 def contact_params
   params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :phone_number, :message, :email)
 end
end
```

because i want to try to see if format.js will run so it's only 1 line

create.js.erb

`console.log('sending alert!');`

index.html.haml

```
.main_contact_inner 
  = form_for @contact , url: contacts_path do |f|
    - if @contact.errors.any?
      %ul 
        - @contact.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg 
    #contactForm.row.contact_form
      .form-group.col-md-4
        = f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Tên' 
      .form-group.col-md-4
        = f.text_field :phone_number, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Số Điện Thoại'
      .form-group.col-md-4
        = f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Email'
      .form-group.col-md-12
        = f.text_area :message, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Tin nhắn', rows: 1
      .form-group.col-md-12
        %button.btn.submit_btn.red.form-control{:type => "submit", :value => "submit"} Gửi đi
```

After creating the contact, no log is displayed on the console.

I don't know why my code can't go into format.js, can anyone help me with this problem?

or can someone show me how to create an alert like sweetalert2 without using controller .

Comment: Hi, you came to the right place for help, and your question is set up pretty well for someone to help.  Could you please show us what your client-side code looks like that calls your Ajax action?  Also, could you please show us more of create.js.erb and not just that one line?  It's hard to answer this question now, but that information might help.

Comment: @RyanPorter i want to check if format.js is working or not so just 1 line in create.js.erb , but it not working.

Comment: Wow neat.  Thai characters in code.  I've never seen that before.

I don't see where you're calling your Ajax action from the client-side HTML?  I suspect that you're not seeing the console output beause your front-end code is not calling the XHR action?

Comment: @RyanPorteri think, just to format.js will automatically call file create.js.erb, can you show me the right thing?

Comment: I think that Joel's answer explains why your front-end code is not calling your XHR action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing `remote: true`

```
= form_for @contact , url: contacts_path, remote: true do |f|
```

[From the documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for):

> :remote - if set to true, will allow Unobtrusive Javascript drivers to
> control the submit behavior

This is what adds the js header to the request and allows the rails controller to respond with the js format.

Answer (score 1):

[From rails guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements)

```
<%= form_with(model: @article, id: "new-article", local: false) do |form| %>
  
<% end %>
```

Add `local: false`